# python-3.5: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0x8e in position 16

Tags: python-3.5

```
    inputfile = 'data3.csv'

    f = open(inputfile, 'r')

    data = f.read()
    #data = data.decode('utf-8')
    #data = data.decode('utf-8')

    def find_differential_expression(data, N=100, max=100000, min=2):  #N is most commonly found genes hits, minimum is the number of repeats for each gene
        datasplit = data.split(",")
        from collections import Counter
        datacount = Counter(datasplit)
        datacount = datacount.most_common(N)
        datacount = [x for x in datacount if x[0] not in ['', '\n','-','- /','- / Blank_Space']]
        datacount = [x for x in datacount if not x[0].startswith("- / ")]
        datacount = [x for x in datacount if x[1] > min]
        datacount = [x for x in datacount if x[1] < max]
        return datacount
```

I am using python 3.5 and getting this kind of error in Anaconda:
`string.decode('utf-8')` does not work. How can I get around this problem? The error message is below.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "<ipython-input-1-79d5084f03e2>", line 6, in <module>
    data = f.read()

  File "//anaconda/lib/python3.5/encodings/ascii.py", line 26, in decode
    return codecs.ascii_decode(input, self.errors)[0]

UnicodeDecodeError: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0x8e in position 16: ordinal not in range(128)
```

Comment: Did you determine the encoding of the file? If it isn't `ascii` or `utf-8` then it isn't `ascii` or `utf-8`.

Comment: @JohnColeman no, its just columns of excel file, saved as data3.csv and imported, and I am trying to count the number of same names in all of the data.

Comment: This suggests that Excel csv files are encoded in an idiosyncratic way: https://donatstudios.com/CSV-An-Encoding-Nightmare Perhaps you could open it in Notepad and then using save-as, explicitly specifying `utf-8` in the encoding, and then import it into Python.